# Need to Import and Convert-HTML for a searched file in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have folders with similar filenames with different time stamps, I can find the latest file from the folder but I am getting an error when importing that particular file to html.

Please someone help me on this.

```
$dir = "C:\ABC\Reports"
$filter="*.csv"
$latest = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Filter $filter | Sort-Object CreationTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
$latest.name
$Dailybackups = Import-Csv -Path $latest.name | ConvertTo-Html -Head $Header
```

Comment: What error do you get? Please provide the full error message.

Comment: Here s the error:      Import-Csv : Could not find file 'C:\Alert\Service_Plan_Completion_Report_2020_01_31_09_18_08.csv'.
At C:\Alert\run.ps1:17 char:17
+ $Dailybackups = Import-Csv -Path $latest.name | ConvertTo-Html -Head $Header
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [Import-Csv], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileOpenFailure,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportCsvCommand

Comment: Use $latest.FullName